# How to align images in R Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a logo right-aligned in the titlePanel, and another logo right-aligned in the "footer". I want to have both images in the same size and I want them both right-aligned to the same "vertical line".

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyApp(

  ui <- fluidPage(

    theme = shinytheme("simplex"),

    titlePanel(

      div("Fancy Title",
          actionLink(inputId = "gitLab",
                     label = tags$img(src = "logo_1.svg", width = "40px", height = "40px"),
                     style = "background-size:cover; background-position:center; position:absolute;right:2em",
                     onclick = "window.open('https://github.com/')")

      )

    ), # end titlePanel

    hr(),
    div(
      width = 10,
      a(href = "https://www.rcsb.org/", "Whatever", target="_blank"),

      actionLink(inputId = "ABC",
                 label = tags$img(src = "logo_2.svg", width = "40px", height = "40px"),
                 style = "background-size:cover; background-position:center; position:absolute;right:2em",
                 onclick = "window.open('https://www.rcsb.org/')")

    ),

    br()

  ), # end fluidPage

  server = function(input, output, session){}

) # end shinyApp
```

So far, I can't manage to align them to the right, so that they both have the same "x-coordinates". Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have limited experience with CSS, but I believe adding one of these to your style might solve your issue:

**style = 'float:right;'**

or

**style = 'text-align:right;'**

or

**style= 'position:absolute; right:42px;'**  (adjust pixels to meet your needs)

Hope this helps.